How to read external zpl file using python SCIP with readProblem
Same issue but not solved (https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/issues/365)
I happen to have the same problem and solving it was/still is a long path.
from pyscipopt import Model
model = Model()
model.readProblem("path\\file.zpl")
model.optimize()

File "src\\pyscipopt\\scip.pxi", line 5353, in pyscipopt.scip.Model.readProblem Parameters File "src\\pyscipopt\\scip.pxi", line 287, in pyscipopt.scip.PY_SCIP_CALL elif rc == SCIP_PLUGINNOTFOUND:
I get the error above, even though zpl files are listed as supported in the documentation (https://pyscipopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/readwrite.html).
When I use file.mps it works
There is function SCIPincludeReaderZpl() (https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/reader__zpl_8h.php), but i dont know how to include it because the source file of that function is in C and i use python.
Do you know what should I do to import that function? I think it will be the proper way of handling zpl files.
